# Add and remove div tag on click jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to add `div` and remove `div` with one class only.

Right now I'm able to do it with two classes.

```
  <div class="optionBox">
<div class="block">
    <input type="text" /> <span class="remove">Remove Option</span>
</div>
<div class="block">
    <input type="text" /> <span class="remove">Remove Option</span>
</div>
<div class="block">
    <span class="add ">Add Option</span>
</div>
```

```
    $('.add').click(function () {
        $('.block:last').before('<div class="block"><input type="text" /><span class="remove">Remove Option</span></div>');

    });

    $(document).on('click', '.remove', function () {
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });
</script>
```

how to do it with one class reference in jquery

Comment: why would you want it with 1 class?

Comment: it like a button when i click once it add item to box and then if i click it again it removes

Comment: So you can only add one item? Not sure why you want it with just one.

Comment: yes, its like shop items

Comment: if a customer click once the item is added to the basket and if the customer click it again it is removed from basket

Comment: What do you mean by "click it again"??? the 'add' and 'remove' are not the same element... how/ why would the user click any of them **again**?

Comment: https://www.otreva.com/calculator/# chk out this website same functionality on

Comment: after clicking get started --> select features  the next page shows  icons which when click once adds div  price to total and if click again removes from total

Comment: Say you clicked to add one, then you want to add another, how would you do that as clicking again would just remove the last one - I don't think this will work if you need to add more than one option

Answer (score 0):

```
 $( this).parent().siblings(".block").remove();
```

You have to catch the parent of the element you want

Comment: where should i write this

Comment: Replace $(this).parent().remove();

Comment: this removes option but then i cannot add back again i have to reload the page

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
$('.add').click(function () {
  var customTemplate = ('<div class="block"><input type="text" /><span class="remove">Remove Option</span></div>')
        $('.block:last').before(customTemplate);

    });

 $(document).off('click', '.remove');
    $(document).on('click', '.remove', function () {
        $(this).parent().remove()
    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/b0bw0u8d/

Comment: i want that when i click add option again it should remove the option

Comment: otreva.com/calculator/#

Comment: check out this website getstarted--> select features--->